# Do NSUserDefaults get synced to iCloud? I don't want them to be

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

I am storing a username/password in NSUserDefaults.
I do not want this information to be backed up to iCloud.

How can I make sure that this does not happen? From the docs, it seems like
NSUserDefaults are not backed up at all unless you use NSUbiquitousKeyStore.

Do I have the right interpretation?

Thanks!

Comment: "I am storing a username/password in NSUserDefaults". D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct. iCloud can do key/value storage but you have to explicitly use this functionality. NSUserDefaults will not get synced with iCloud because the defaults pList stored on disk is not within the ubiquity container.